# How to set up dynamic url in Google Analytics Goal Set up?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics

I'm looking to set up Analytics Goal for Order Complete, but the URL generates dynamic Order ID on it,

1. Cart : /cart
2. Add Shipping Info: /app/index.php?i=1&c=entry&m=ewei_shopv2&do=mobile&r=pc.order.create
3. Select Payment page: /app/index.php?i=1&c=entry&m=ewei_shopv2&do=mobile&r=pc.order.pay&id=1350
4. Order Complete:  /app/index.php?i=1&c=entry&m=ewei_shopv2&do=mobile&r=pc.order.pay.success&id=1350&result=1

How should i enter Payment/Order complete field , appreciate your help.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can set a goal when page path contains `r=pc.order.pay.success` which is a unique value in querystring in the purchase path.